# Ставится ли запятая перед "и" в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, союзы, и

Ненавижу таких людей, которые при малейшей ссоре начинают вспоминать всё плохое, что между вами происходило, и всё равно продолжают общаться

Comment: Предложение кончается точкой.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна. Она бы не ставилась перед союзом "и" между двумя однородными членами (сказуемыми), но тут есть придаточное "что между вами происходило", которое заканчивается как раз перед этим союзом и обособляется по общему правилу.

По поводу "вами" и "нами". Niemand ошибается. "Вами" вполне корректно.